# How to share code between a regular Angular component and an Angular Element?

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-elements

Lets assume that I'll use nx to be able to share libraries between different sites in a mono repo.
I have two sites:

- Site 1: Angular App
- Site 2: Static Site

Site 1 has a helloWorld Angular Component.
On site 2 I want to use the helloWorld component, but as a web component created by an Angular Element. All the Angular Components and Elements should be stored in a shared, external nx library.

Is there a way to share code between the regular Angular Component and the Angular Element? Or, nest the regular component inside the element?

Comment: maybe you can add more details about what kinds of data are you hoping to share between the 2? are these 2 components on the same server and contained in the same angular project?

Comment: Thanks @Rick. There is no data shared between the 2. The helloWorld component simply outputs "Hello World!". There is no Angular app for site 2. It should use only Angular Elements.

Comment: You could try to convert the common shared components into their own library, the Elements and the regular angular app could then both import what they needed from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a possible solution in a few steps.

#### 1. Generate a library

The first step is to generate nx library where you want to store shared custom elements.
`nx g lib custom-elements`

Add build step for this library in `angular.json` with something like:

```
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/libs/custom-elements",
            "index": "libs/custom-elements/src/lib/index.html",
            "main": "libs/custom-elements/src/lib/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "libs/custom-elements/tsconfig.lib.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [],
            "styles": [],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "none",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
```

The main part there is `"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",`, because we will use files built by this library later.
Also don't forget to add empty `index.html` file.

#### 2. Mark your angular components as custom elements

Firstly, add angular elements `npm install @angular/elements`.
Then mark the components you want to share using `createCustomElement`:

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [BrowserModule],
   entryComponents: [SomeComponent],
})
export class SharedComponentsModule {
   constructor(readonly injector: Injector) {
       const ngElement = createCustomElement(SomeComponent, {
           injector,
       });

       customElements.define('some-component', ngElement);
   }

   ngDoBootstrap() {}
}
```

#### 3. Build the library and add necessary scripts to your static page

Run `nx build custom-elements`. You will get all the files in `dist/libs/custom-elements`. You are now able to add them to any page and use custom elements!

#### Working example

I created a working example here https://github.com/nickbullock/share-custom-elements-between-angular-and-static-app

How to run angular app: `npm start`
How to run static app: `npm run app2:serve`

#### Additional read

https://indepth.dev/posts/1116/angular-web-components-a-complete-guide

https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/how-to-compile-your-angular-components-library-into-web-components-47ff0ac73bd7

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to share **code** between the regular Angular Component and
> the Angular Element?

Yes, This is why we use libraries. *Libraries are not just a way to share code in Nx. They are also useful for factoring out code into small units with a well-defined public API*. The NX recommends having a [small number of library types](https://nx.dev/latest/angular/structure/library-types).

According to [angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/elements), *Angular elements are Angular components packaged as custom elements (also called **Web Components**)*, so what you need is [Nx Plugin for Web](https://nx.dev/latest/angular/web/overview) which *contains generators for managing **Web Component** applications and libraries within an Nx workspace*. You may need the helpful instructions inside [Create Libs in Angular using NX](https://nx.dev/latest/angular/tutorial/08-create-libs) to meet your purpose.

> Is there a way to nest the regular component inside the element?

Yes, As Angular allows us to put reusable logic into the separate units.